# .htaccess RewiteRule Variable Issue

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I am wanting to create redirect for urls using .htaccess

http://shows.example.com/showtitle/sitemap.xml

to map to my existing folder structure what is like

http://shows.example.com/sitemaps/sitemap_shows_showtitle_3day.xml

two variable the subdomain which can differ and the showtitle

so i wrote

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z]*)/sitemap.xml
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    http://%1.example.com/sitemaps/sitemap_%1_$1_3day.xml [L]
```

which redirects to

http://superstar.example.com/sitemaps/sitemap_superstar__3day.xml

Do i need to combine both RewriteCond into one to access both variables? Or can I get the variables from as they are?

Comment: Where's this `.htaccess` file located?  And what request is it handling?  It doesn't add up for the `$1` to be an empty string.

Comment: the .htaccess is located in the root directory, i'm just passing the example url through http://shows.example.com/showtitle/sitemap.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working this way.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)/sitemap.xml http://%1.example.com/sitemaps/sitemap_%1_$1_3day.xml [L,R=302]
```